# What is the most effective way to style mobile apps natively using Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile, dropdown

Flutter already provides libraries for Material Design and Cupertino which aligns to Android and iOS design specific.

My question is in order to achieve mobile native look on different platforms, what's the best approach?

I presume there might be some principles to follow

1. Use Material Design and Cupertino libraries respectively (for instance, TextButton, Scaffold and CupertinoButton , CupertinoTabScaffold for Andriod and iOS.
2. Use widgets for platform specific, for instance, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets

It seems the widgets for iOS platform are currently limited compared with the given widgets(components) for instance, there is no iOS cart implementation for that.
Or did not find the pull-down dropdown like that https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691248

Not the timer picker styling here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is opinon-based. The most effective way depends on what your app will look like, which components you need to use and how native it actually has too look. I mean it is possible to write a native app without having a typical "native" look and feel to the components.

For good or bad, depending on your preference and what you value... Flutter does not transpile into native components but instead handles the rendering of each pixel itself. This means that in order to use "native-components", those must be implemented and available, either by Flutter or by a package (or yourself). So there will always be, or at least always be a risk, that components are available on each native platform that is not (yet) available in Flutter.